# Wirelessly install app from XCode on (jailbroken) iDevice

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, jailbreak, wireless

I build my app for iPhone (without code-signing, with help of Jailcoder utility). How to install it on my jailbroken device over Wi-Fi? I need only to install it, without running/debugging from XCode.

As an approach I tried to pack it as `IPA` and download in `Installous`, but installation failed with `unexpected content` error message.

Is there a working method?

Comment: Do you want an Xcode **Build** process to automatically install the app on your device, or do you just want *some* way to install the app, after having built it with Xcode?

Comment: Some way. I don't need to debug it on device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it via `Installous`. Previously the build was not configured for my device and thats why there was an error.

Steps:

- archive build in `XCode` (`Product->Archive`)
- reveal the archive folder in finder, get `app` folder from it
- place `app` folder into `Payload` folder and compress this all
- change extension from `.zip` to `.ipa`
- in `Installous` get device IP adress, than enter it in desktop browser
- upload `ipa` file

Answer (score 0):

I found basic instructions for transferring IPA's to jailbroken iPhones over WiFi here: http://www.ehow.com/how_12098417_send-ipa-ipod-touch.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by generating a build, transferring it to your device using sftp, and then installing it on the device by using installipa. [Here is a tutorial](http://highaltitudehacks.com/2013/07/25/ios-application-security-part-7-installing-and-running-custom-applications-on-device-without-a-registered-developer-account) i wrote on it.